# angular 4 mergeMap issue

Tags: javascript, angular

i am working with angularfire and i need to "JOIN" two nodes on the key.
this is my method:

```
  mergetest(userkey){
return this.db.list(`userOwnHangouts/${userkey}`)
  .mergeMap((hangouts) => {
    console.log('the merge hangout: ', hangouts.$key) //undefined
    return this.db.list(`hangoutInterestedUsers/${hangouts.$key}`)
  })
  .subscribe(x => console.log('subscribe: ', x))
 }
```

as you can see, when i try to get the $key it is undefined. although if i log just hangouts i do get an array of objects.

how can i use the mergeMap to return one observable that include BOTH the resuls of the first query and the second query? in this case, the hangouts themselves and the users that belong to them?

in the console i get:
[image]

these are the 2 nodes that i want to join:
[image]
[image]

@Maximus this is the result i get can i get all the objects in an array to use then with ngFor?
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in general case:

```
return this.db.list(`userOwnHangouts/${userkey}`)
   // flattening the array returned by `list()`
  .mergeMap((o) => {
    return o;
  })
  .mergeMap((o) => {
    return this.db.list(`hangoutInterestedUsers/${o['$key']}`).map((users) => {
       return {...o, users: users};
    });
  })
  .reduce((acc, v) => {
    acc.push(v);
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .subscribe(x => console.log('subscribe: ', x))
 }
```

#### Edit:

But because both `this.db.list` never completes we can't use `reduce` here. Also `forkJoin` won't work for the same  reason. So the way to  go is `combineLatest`:

```
this.db.list(`userOwnHangouts/${userkey}`)
    .switchMap((list: any[]) => Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
        list.map((item: any) => this.db.list(`hangoutInterestedUsers/${item['$key']}`)),
        (...results: any[][]) => {
            list.forEach((item: any, index: number) => {
                item["users"] = results[index];
            });
            return list;
        }
    ))
    .subscribe(x => console.log('subscribe: ', x))
```

Comment: why do i get 2 FirebaseListObservable even though i have subscribe?

Comment: i get: Property '$key' does not exist on type '{}' regarding the o.$key

Comment: how can i add an image to a comment?

Comment: i added the console into the question itself

Comment: i have used o['$key']. and i do get the users but without the hangouts themselves. i need the results from BOTH queries

Comment: do you need both `hangouts` and `hangoutInterestedUsers`? how this structure should look?

Comment: each hangout has a key, and in another node i have users under that key, so i need to join those 2 to get the hangouts and their users

Comment: I understand, show what output you expect in the log

Comment: i added the 2 nodes to the question. i need the data from both, i would assume something like inside the hangout to have an array of users. i thought mergeMap should flatten both to one

Comment: I need to see how you expect the values to come out in the log, can you write that?

Comment: i use angularfire, so after subscribing i would assume something like this:     let example = [
      {
        hangoutTitle: 'sometitle',
        users:[
          {username: 'name'},
          {username: 'name2'},
        ]
      },
      {
        hangoutTitle: 'sometitle2',
        users:[
          {username: 'name'},
          {username: 'name2'},
        ]
      }
    ] something i can loop and display each hangout and a list of its users

Comment: @cartant, hey, is there any implementation that avoid using `mergeMap` twice?

Comment: it does work. i get each object but can i get them wrapped in an array to loop them with ngFor?  i'll add an image to the question.

Comment: and can you explain this line?: return {...o, users: users}; i mean the 3 dots?

Comment: I've updated the answer. You need `reduce` operator for that. The three dots is a copy operator of object properties, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literalsSpread_in_object_literals)

Comment: sorry, man, can't spend any more time with you, the solution is working for me, I've tested it. check for errors, log what you get inside `reduce`, read about the operators I've used etc... try to do something yourself

Comment: hey, first i already did. thank you for all the help. i log inside the reduce and the data is there in the correct form, but the return is nothing. in anycase, i did the same logic of pushing in the second mergeMap:        arr.push({...o, users: users});
       return arr; and it works. i can loop the deta and display it

Comment: @Ron, yeah, you can then ask another specific question for `reduce` if you see that you get the correct data into `reduce`

Comment: @Ron, hey, I figured out why `reduce` didn't emit anything. The firebase observables never complete. You have to use different solution. See my edit